# Assertation Failure in CorePlot

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have recently started testing my application on my iPhone 6 plus and when selecting a data point using coreplot from a graph I drew, I error messages such as the following:

Assertion failure in -[CPTXYPlotSpace setYRange:], /Users/joshhamet/Downloads/core-plot-release_1.5.1/framework/Source/CPTXYPlotSpace.m:416

However it works with my iPhone 5 perfectly fine, so I was curious if someone could explain how to fix this.  Here's some code. Thanks!

```
-(void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
/*Set the index selected and call for graph to be redrawn so selected symbol will be red*/
self.indexSelected=idx;
[self.graph reloadData];

CPTPlotRange *newXRange=[CPTPlotRange new];

/*If we have a daily graph, we need to calculate the x coordinate ourselves*/
if([self.graphTitle isEqualToString:@"Daily"]){
    double location=[[self xIndexForDailyGraph:idx]doubleValue]-1;
    if(location<=0)
        newXRange=[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(2)];
    else
        newXRange=[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(location) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(2)];
}

/*Monthly and Weekly graphs x coordinate*/
else{
    if(!idx){
        newXRange=[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(idx) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(2)];
    }
    else{
        newXRange=[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(idx-1) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(2)];
    }
}

/*Determine the y index of the index (Depends on the current day or month)*/
if([self.graphTitle isEqualToString:@"Weekly"]){
    NSInteger weekday=[[NSCalendar currentCalendar]component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    idx=(weekday+idx)%7;
}
if([self.graphTitle isEqualToString:@"Monthly"]){
    NSInteger currentMonth=[[NSCalendar currentCalendar]component:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    idx=(currentMonth+idx)%12;
}

double selectedPoint=[[self.urinationDataArray[idx] objectForKey:@"amountOfUrine"]doubleValue];
CPTPlotRange *newYRange=[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(selectedPoint-10) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(20)];

[CPTAnimation animate:self.plotSpace property:@"xRange" fromPlotRange:self.plotSpace.xRange toPlotRange:newXRange duration:.1 animationCurve:CPTAnimationCurveCubicInOut delegate:self];
[CPTAnimation animate:self.plotSpace property:@"yRange" fromPlotRange:self.plotSpace.yRange toPlotRange:newYRange duration:.1 animationCurve:CPTAnimationCurveCubicInOut delegate:self];

/*Add Text Annotation*/
[self addAnnotationAtRecordIndex:idx forPlot:plot];
}
```

Comment: That [assertion](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/release_1.5.1/framework/Source/CPTXYPlotSpace.m#L416) means that something tried to change the `yRange` to `nil`. Do you have a stack trace with the crash? Is it crashing in response to some action from your app, or something internal to Core Plot (e.g., an animation)?

Comment: it's in response to an animation.  When the user clicks on a data point in the graph, i animate the axes to zoom in on the data point so setXRange and setYRange throw assertations.

Comment: @EricSkroch I added the function where it fails, right when CPTAnimation is called. I also checked to make sure I wasnt setting the ranges to nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Core Plot. I believe it has been fixed in the latest code on [GitHub](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot). You'll need to pull the latest code and build Core Plot from source. Look at the [change log](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/master/documentation/changelog.markdown) to see everything that has changed since 1.5.1.